# Error from mysql delete

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-delete

I don't understand why I've got an error

> "Erreur de syntaxe près de '1' à la ligne 1"

(sorry I'm french ...)

Here is my code

> ```
> $post_id=$_POST["del_id"];
> $post_photo=$_POST["del_photo"];
>
> $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM produits WHERE id='$post_id'");
> $ok=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
> if ($ok) {
>   $small=$post_photo."_small.jpg";
>   $large=$post_photo."_large.jpg";
>   if (file_exists($small)) unlink($small);
>   if (file_exists($large)) unlink($large);
> }
> ```

However, the mysql delete works fine but my two jpg's still here due to error.

Comment: $query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM produits WHERE id='$post_id'"); -- check if you are getting rows by this query in your code.

Comment: there is no syntax error in the above code you may need to post the complete code to see whats going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language

Answer (score 0):

To Zafar Malik : Yes the select works fine

Here is the full code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["del_id"])) {
    $post_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["del_id"]);
    $post_photo=$_POST["del_photo"];

    $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM produits WHERE id='$post_id'");
    $ok=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($ok) {
        $small=$post_photo."_small.jpg";
        $large=$post_photo."_large.jpg";
        if (file_exists($small)) unlink($small);
        if (file_exists($large)) unlink($large);
    }
    header("location: admin.php?page=produits");
}

titre_h1("NOHOME", "LISTE DES PRODUITS", "SUPPRIMER UN PRODUIT");

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $get_id=$_GET["id"];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produits WHERE id='$get_id'");
    $nbreLignes = mysql_num_rows($query);

    echo "<div id='welcome'>\n";
    echo "<form id='formulaire' name='produits_del' action='admin.php?page=produits_del' method='post'>\n";

    if ($nbreLignes > 0) {
        $donnees = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='del_id' value='".$get_id."'>\n";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='del_photo' value='".$repimages.$donnees['photo']."'>\n";
        echo "  CONFIRMEZ-VOUS LA SUPPRESSION DU PRODUIT ?\n";
        echo "  <div class='del_name'>".iso_strtoupper_fr($donnees['nom'])."</div>\n";
        echo "  <div style='margin-bottom:15px;'>\n";
        echo "      Origine : ".$donnees['origine']."<br />\n";
        echo "      Catégorie : ".$donnees['categorie']."<br />\n";
        if ($donnees['scategorie']!='') echo "      Sous Catégorie : ".$donnees['scategorie']."<br />\n";
        echo "      <br /><img src='".$repimages.$donnees['photo']."_small.jpg' />\n";
        echo "  </div>\n";
        echo "  <div class='bouton del_bouton'><a class='valider'>SUPPRIMER</a></div>\n";
        echo "  <div class='bouton del_bouton' style='float:right;'><a class='annuler'>ANNULER</a></div>\n";
        } else {
        echo "  CE PRODUIT N'EXISTE PAS\n";
        echo "  <div class='bouton del_bouton' style='float:none;width:100%'><a class='annuler'>RETOUR À LA LISTE DES PRODUITS</a></div>\n";
    }
} else {
    header("location: admin.php?page=produits");
}

echo "</form>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
?>
```

Comment: No one can help me here please ?

Answer (score 0):

**To change the language that MySQL uses when reporting you need to change the my.ini file as follows**

> POST:
>   [WAMP/MySQL errors not in correct language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language)