# WAMP/MySQL errors not in correct language

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I've re-installed WAMP multiple times, searched literally hundreds of pages, and its not fixed this issue:

[image]

I've looked inside the phpmyadmin config files, set:

```
$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';
```

Uninstalled multiple times (as mentioned) and seemed to have no luck what so ever. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does that error actually translate as?

Comment: @MackieeE: "no database selected"

Comment: I have no clue. On my SAMP server i am (deliberately) making mysql errors, it's looking like:

(error #1045) Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'Dobby'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI). So the default language (google) is french, odd. I'm interested in changing it though, since i have no clue how to read french.

Comment: @user3664313 Try the answers from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8542961)

Comment: Change the installer version

Comment: Still the same thing guys (thanks so far though). PC Language is English, everything else is too. @SyedQarib i'm using the one from the wampserver website. Is there any other versions?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

To change the language that MySQL uses when reporting you need to change the `my.ini` file as follows.

Find this line:

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

And change it to your prefered language, for example:

```
lc-messages=en_GB
```

To change it to English US, you can do like this:

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

Save the file and then restart MySQL.

```
left click wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> Service -> Restart Service
```

Remember the guys that produce WampServer are French so I guess thats why this has been added to the `my.ini` file, and they just forgot to remove it on this release.

#### How to Find my.ini in WAMPServer

Use the wampmanager menus like so :-

```
left click wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

This will load the my.ini file into your editor.

> Here you can find a list of [valid locales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html)

Comment: Searching for the command may be easier as it is not on the first few lines. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I set mine to: lc-messages=morse_CODE and now my errors are coming out like this:

-.-- --- ..- / .... .- ...- . / .- -. / . .-. .-. --- .-. / .. -. / -.-- --- ..- .-. / -- -.-- ... --.- .-.. / ... -.-- -. - .- -..-

Comment: @JamesWilson Whatever floats your boat

Comment: i just wonder why it is set as fr_FR by default. was deployed in production, before we ever knew.

Comment: after setting the language to `en_GB` or `en_US` using `lc-messages` you should restart mysql server.

Comment: who uses french anyway as default production language

Comment: @DrDeo Well like I said in the asnwer, the nice people at AlterWay are French, so I assume while testing a release they find it useful to see messages in their own language!

Comment: And if you're an American English fan, use en_US instead of en_GB :)

Answer (score 4):

Change the following settings in my.ini file

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

To permanently change the language preferences
[image]

Comment: This answer (formatting aside) is a duplicate of the already-accepted answer.  Did you have something additional to add?

Answer (score 2):

`$cfg['Lang'] = 'en-utf-8';` and friends change the language for phpmysql, not for the mysql server, so anything coming from the database server itself will be unaffected.

You need to start the server daemon with `--lc_messages=en_US` (or put that in the relevant config file), for a per-session setting just use `SET lc_messages = 'en_US';`

Comment: How do i do the `--lc_messages=en_US` in windows? :S

Comment: IIRC you just put it into `my.ini` or `my.cnf`, whatever you have, in the `[mysqld]` section, like `lc_messages = en_US`, ofcourse you need to restart the server. Haven't used Windows in a long time, though.