# Changing the language for MySQL JDBC SQLException messages

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

I made a simple localhost MySQL server and wrote a main method to connect to it.

When entering the wrong username/password an SQLException is thrown, but the description 
of this error is in French.

I changed my phpMyAdmin to English, I downloaded the MySQL Connector for Java (which I expect is also English).

Why are the messages appearing in French and how can I get them to appear in English?

Comment: Found the anwser at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language.

Sorry for the duplicate.