# Laravel's debug messages - partly French. How can I turn it into English?

Tags: laravel-4

My locally installed Laravel's debug messages show partly in French (shown in the image below). How can I turn it into English?

[image: See the text inconnu dans]

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that's not Laravel but rather the MySQL server showing errors in french. Maybe you'll find the solution [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) for the right direction. I am using WAMP Server and MySQL was generating the errors in French. The solution was posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language) in stackoverflow by [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly)

I am repeating here the process for anyone else who get into the same trouble:

Go into my.ini file and look for the following:

```
# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

Replace it with English

```
lc-messages=en_GB
```