# Not able to run my Magento files on wamp server locally for testing

Tags: php, mysql, magento, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to run my Magento files on wamp server locally to test an e-commerce website on Windows 7.

For configuring Magento on my wamp server i reffered [this documentation](http://insync.co.in/how-to-install-magento-on-wamp-server-localhost-localcomputer/)  and as per the instructions given i installed magento on my wamp server.

After installation i uploaded my Magento files on it.
[image: Wamp Server homepage where i can see my project folder named as niraame_running_on_06062015]

But when i am clicking on it i am getting error which says that -->> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

[image: Error massage when running my Magento file by using link localhost/niraame_running_on_06062015]

I changed the link as http://localhost/niraame_running_on_06062015/index.php but this time i again recived the same massage with another log number
[image: Error massage when i run the website using localhost/niraame_running_on_06062015/index]

Sir i am into testing profile and first time i am testing a website which is build on Majento. I am not able to open the website locally for testing. I have the source code with me but since i am new to Magento i don't know how to use Wamp and Magento together. I reffered almost all available documentation regarding this but still not able to run the website.

---

Since i was not able to add the complete error report here so i am adding this answer which containg the complete error report for 1185848077

```
a:4:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur:  'niraamec_user'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)";i:1;s:2541:"#0   C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55197):  Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55677): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(53869): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(54927): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55785): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(30015): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(29956): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(12175): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(12205): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(12190): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(21534): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(23147): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(23027): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(20764): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\includes\src\__default.php(20694): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 C:\wamp\www\Niraame_Running_On_06062015\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:38:"/niraame_running_on_06062015/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:38:"/niraame_running_on_06062015/index.php";}
```

Sir i am not able to figure out what causing this error.

Comment: It's failing to log into the database => Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur => Access denied for user. Wrong credentials or user doesn't have permissions to use the database.

Comment: You could start by changing the error message language from French to a language you understand. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802970/wamp-mysql-errors-not-in-correct-language)

Comment: @Sweta Singh Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Muk No Sir, its not solved but i am accessing the application by an alternate way now

Answer (score 1):

Go to `magento/var/report` and open the file with the Error log record number name `i.e 1185848077` in your case. In that file you can find the complete description of the error.
For log files like `system.log` and `exception.log`, go to `magento/var/log/`.

Comment: Sir i went to magento/var but inside var folder i am getting 3 sub folders maned as cache, package and session. There is nothing named as Report.

Comment: You can enable printing errors by renaming file local.xml.sample to local.xml. file location magentoRootDirectory/errors/

Comment: Sir where i should put my majento file. Inside the wamp/majento folder or i should put it separately inside the wamp folder

Comment: put it separately inside the wamp folder

Comment: Sir i changed local.xml.sample to local.xml but still i am not able to print/get the error reports

Comment: I am getting the reports now

Comment: Sir what a:4:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'niraamec_user'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)";i:1;s:2701:"#0 E:\WampServer\wamp\www\NiraameRunningOn06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55197): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()   error means

Answer (score 0):

**First**

if your project is the new project, remove the

> niraame_running_on_06062015/app/etc/local.xml to get the new setting
>   of installation.

if not, maybe you forgot to put your db for your magento, check your **app/etc/local.xml**

---

**Second**

check

> niraame_running_on_06062015/var/report/1185848077

open it with text editor. and read what's the error.

---

**Tips**

check your index.php

set the IsDeveloperMode to be true and comment this

```
// if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
// }
```

Comment: Sir how to remove it and from where. Are you telling me to delete the niraame_running_on_06062015/app/etc/local.xml file from  niraame_running_on_06062015   folder

Comment: I am able to get the report now

Comment: just rename local.xml to _local.xml bro

Comment: Sir i added the report as an answer which i am getting

Comment: that one because your password is different with your local mysql password. change it to be same or change it in local.xml

Comment: Sir what a:4:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'niraamec_user'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)";i:1;s:2701:"#0 E:\WampServer\wamp\www\NiraameRunningOn06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55197): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()   error means

Comment: @SwetaSingh that one because your mysql password and username might be incorrect. recheck about that

Answer (score 0):

You must set correct database params. Please open app/etc/local.xml and replace

> @localhost to localhost

or just remove local.xml and reinstall magento

Comment: Sir what a:4:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'niraamec_user'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)";i:1;s:2701:"#0 E:\WampServer\wamp\www\NiraameRunningOn06062015\includes\src\__default.php(55197): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()   error means

Comment: Either the database was set up with the wrong username/password or the app/etc/local.xml has something wrong with the name/password supplied to log into the database. Or the user hasn't been granted rights to use the database.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error, and fixed it by creating one new db user.

I believe it had been caused by mixed db user so when you have this error, try to use one totally new created db user, it should be helpful